# How do I direct awk to leave floating point numbers unchanged, but append a .0 to integer numbers?

Tags: awk

I have a csv file that, apart from the first column, consists of float and integer numbers (no scientific notation). I would like to output another csv file with the same content, but where all numbers are guaranteed to have a decimal point and at least one digit after it. E.g.:

- 0 becomes 0.0
- 123 becomes 123.0
- 3.3 remains the same
- 333.3333 remains the same

I am using awk like

```bash
LC_NUMERIC=C
awk 'NR>=1 { FS=OFS=","; for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) $i=sprintf("%f", $i) } 1' "input.csv" > output.csv
```

But the result, with the "%f" format specifier, is that 123 remains 123 (doesn't become 123.0).

With "%.1f" I get exactly one digit after the decimal point, and 333.3333 becomes 333.3, instead I want it unchanged.

Is there a format specifier I could use? Or some other way to achieve the same thing?

[EDIT with sample]

`test.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LC_NUMERIC=C
awk 'NR>=1 { FS=OFS=","; for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) $i=sprintf("%f", $i) } 1' "input.csv" >output.csv
```

`input.csv`

```
gene_name,VarXCRep.1,VarXCRep.2,VarXCRep.3,VarX1Rep.1,VarX1Rep.2,VarX1Rep.3
Soltu.DM.01G000010,360.7000522,361.5910696,333.0843759,395.2279977,386.8290979,377.756613
Soltu.DM.01G000070,2,540,0,0,1.83331326,0
```

`output.csv`

```
gene_name,VarXCRep.1,VarXCRep.2,VarXCRep.3,VarX1Rep.1,VarX1Rep.2,VarX1Rep.3
Soltu.DM.01G000010,360.700052,361.591070,333.084376,395.227998,386.829098,377.756613
Soltu.DM.01G000070,2.000000,540.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.833313,0.000000
```

`desired output`

```
gene_name,VarXCRep.1,VarXCRep.2,VarXCRep.3,VarX1Rep.1,VarX1Rep.2,VarX1Rep.3
Soltu.DM.01G000010,360.7000522,361.5910696,333.0843759,395.2279977,386.8290979,377.756613
Soltu.DM.01G000070,2.0,540.0,0.0,0.0,1.83331326,0.0
```

Comment: Not sure if it would be useful in this particular case, but you might find *dynamic width and prec capability* described in [Format Modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) handy if you need to have format depending on value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } NR>1{ for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^-?[0-9]+$/) $i=$i".0" } 1' input.csv
gene_name,VarXCRep.1,VarXCRep.2,VarXCRep.3,VarX1Rep.1,VarX1Rep.2,VarX1Rep.3
Soltu.DM.01G000010,360.7000522,361.5910696,333.0843759,395.2279977,386.8290979,377.756613
Soltu.DM.01G000070,2.0,540.0,0.0,0.0,1.83331326,0.0
```

I moved the setting of `FS` back to the `BEGIN` section as it's too late in the `{ ... }` part as the first line has already been split on spaces by then. I also changed the `NR>=1` test to `NR>1` as it's impossible to reach that part of the code with NR `0` or less and what you actually want to do is skip the first line, the header.

I'm using the comparison `/^-?[0-9]+$/` so it ONLY changes integers, it won't change non-numeric strings, IP addresses, floating point or exponential notation numbers or anything else.

Comment: this will miss the negative numbers!

Comment: @karakfa The OP doesn't appear to have any negative numbers but if they did they could always put a `-?` at the start of the regexp. I went ahead and added that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a check if the digits already have a literal decimal digit and then add the precision for those that don't have them.

The answer takes an assumption that the fields from 2 to the end of the row are numerals and not strings, as it does not perform a check if its a numeric before adding the precision.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
     NR>1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if ( $i !~ /[.]/ ) $i = sprintf("%.1f", $i)}1' input.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach which works with negative numbers as well...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR>1  {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i==int($i)"") $i=$i".0"}1' file
```